# Web Crawler for notice of assessment retrieval

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Context**: I want to check if notice of assessment are valid.
**What I did**: I wrote some code to extract textual information from PDF (with OCR on image contained in the PDF): `numfiscal` and `refavis`

What I expose in this code: based on the website of government I check validity of my notice of assessment doing a post request with relatives numfiscal and refavis.

What are your recommendations for this code ? (Any advice will be good since I am mainly autodidact with really little experience in coding practices).

```
import requests
import lxml.html
from pprint import pprint
import re
from ..config import myconfig # My config for proxy, 
from ..utilities.utils import normalize_text,lazyproperty,write_csv,timer #See the end i put the functions
 



class ForbiddenAccess(Exception):
     pass


class IMPOTCrawler():

    impot_url = 'https://cfsmsp.impots.gouv.fr/secavis/faces/commun/index.jsf'

    def __init__(self,numfiscal,refavis):
        self.numfiscal = numfiscal
        self.refavis = refavis
        self.data = {'numfiscal':self.numfiscal,'refavis':self.refavis}

    def _request(self):
        proxies = {"http": myconfig.PROXY_HTTP,"https": myconfig.PROXY_HTTPS}
        data = {'j_id_7:spi':self.numfiscal,'j_id_7:num_facture':self.refavis,'j_id_7_SUBMIT':'1','javax.faces.ViewState':'RxJe/1JKTJSr3aiM3H9DqZq0DrwqEXsY7Rw4eLRgEBsCF1IALJGqVgWTaQkiKbbdcGDWW774BWUCa/+j2CDznhw1/3bxJteY6ZCui66yNevhkej4xuyrFMte5KQnKORt9JZrOQ==','j_id_7:j_id_l':'Valider'}    
        req = requests.post(IMPOTCrawler.impot_url,data=data,proxies=proxies)
        html = req.text
        self.req_ok = req.ok
        self.data.update({'req_ok':self.req_ok})
        return req.ok, html

    @lazyproperty
    def html_content(self):
        _, html = self._request()
        return html

    def is_valid(self):
        if re.findall("Adresse déclarée au",self.html_content):
            self.data.update({"is_valid__online":True,"Request_message":None})
            return True
        elif re.findall("La référence saisie ne correspond pas à un avis présent dans la base.",self.html_content):
            self.data.update({"is_valid__online":False,"Request_message":"Avis non présent dans la base gouvernementale"})
            return False
        elif re.findall("Vous devez vérifier les identifiants saisis.",self.html_content):
            self.data.update({"is_valid__online":False,"Request_message":"Mauvais identifiants"})
            return False
        elif re.findall("Accès Interdit",self.html_content):
            raise ForbiddenAccess("Accès interdit: trop de requêtes")
        

    def parse_info(self):
        valid = self.is_valid()
        if not valid:
            return 
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(self.html_content)
        xpath = "//div[@id='conteneur']//div[@id='principal']//table"
        tab = tree.xpath(xpath)[0]
        tbody = tab.find('tbody')
        rows = tbody.findall("tr")
        infos = []
        infosdic = {}
        #Retrieve informations
        for i,row in enumerate(rows):
            cols = row.findall("td")
            for j,col in enumerate(cols):
                text = col.text
                if text:
                    normtext = re.sub('[\n|\t]','',normalize_text(text).lower())
                    text = re.sub('[\n|\t]','',text)
                    infos.append(text)
                    infosdic[(i,j)]=text
        schema = {'NOM_DECL_1':(1,1),'NOM_NAIS_DECL_1':(2,1),'PRENOM_DECL_1':(3,1),'DATE_NAIS_DECL_1':(4,1),
                    'NOM_DECL_2':(1,2),'NOM_NAIS_DECL_2':(2,2),'PRENOM_DECL_2':(3,2),'DATE_NAIS_DECL_2':(4,2)}
        parsed_infos = {key:infosdic[value] for key,value in schema.items()}
        for i,elt in enumerate(infos):     
            if "Adresse déclarée au" in elt:
                if  "Date de mise en recouvrement de " in infos[i+5]:
                    parsed_infos['ADRESSE'] = "{}, {}".format(infos[i+1],infos[i+4])
                else:
                    parsed_infos['ADRESSE'] = "{}, {}".format(infos[i+1],infos[i+4],infos[i+6])
            if "Revenu fiscal de référence" in elt:
                parsed_infos['REV_FISC'] = normalize_text(infos[i+1])
        self.data.update(parsed_infos)
        return parsed_infos
```

### `utilities.utils`

```
def normalize_text(input_str):
    import unicodedata
    nfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', input_str)
    return nfd_form.encode('ascii','ignore').decode('ascii')

def write_csv(filepath,dic):
    headers = list(dic.keys())
    with open(filepath,'a',newline='') as f:
        f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f,headers)
        if f.tell()==0:
            f_csv.writeheader()        
        f_csv.writerow(dic)
        
def read_csv(filepath,colname=None):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        f_csv =csv.DictReader(f)
        res = []
        if colname:
            for row in f_csv:
                res.append(row[colname])
        else:
            for row in f_csv:
                res.append(row)

    return res    

def timer(method):
    import time
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kwargs)  # note the function call!
        end = time.time()
        print('Elapsed time for: {} is: {} s'.format(method.__name__,(end-start)))
        return result
    return wrapper

Edit: Project on: https://github.com/laurent-pincemaille/Impots-ocr
```

Comment: did you finalize this project ? I would like to know if you have a repo available on github ?

Answer (score 2):

### Error checking

```
    req = requests.post(IMPOTCrawler.impot_url,data=data,proxies=proxies)
    self.req_ok = req.ok
    self.data.update({'req_ok':self.req_ok})
    return req.ok, html
```

First of all, you're passing around `ok` in at least three places: `self.data`, the first element of the return tuple, and `self.req_ok`. That "three" should go down to "zero". It's not a great idea to make a surprise side-effect of `_request` that modifies `self`, and it's generally a better idea to use the Python exception-handling system instead of passing around error values. To this end, rather than paying attention to `req.ok`, simply call `req.raise_for_status()`. If you need to handle an exception that results, then do so with a `try / except`.

Second of all, you're actually just dropping your error status:

```
    _, html = self._request()
```

which you shouldn't. Errors matter, particularly with network operations.

### data

What is `self.data`? So far it looks like a random grab-bag of unrelated things that you write to and never read from. Can this just go away?

### Proxies

Consider saving a `requests.session` to your crawler object, and setting its proxies only once via its `proxies` attribute during your `__init__`.

### Silent failure

Are you *sure* that

```
def parse_info(self):
    valid = self.is_valid()
    if not valid:
        return
```

should silently fail, without logging anything or even returning a boolean?

### Regular expression precompilation

You use

```
re.sub('[\n|\t]'
```

in a method, in a doubly-nested loop. This is a good candidate for `re.compile` in static class scope.

### Formatting

Is this:

```
parsed_infos['ADRESSE'] = "{}, {}".format(infos[i+1],infos[i+4],infos[i+6])
```

correct? It looks like you have one too few fields in your format string.

### Generators

```
def read_csv(filepath,colname=None):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        f_csv =csv.DictReader(f)
        res = []
        if colname:
            for row in f_csv:
                res.append(row[colname])
        else:
            for row in f_csv:
                res.append(row)

    return res
```

can become

```
def read_csv(filepath, colname=None):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        f_csv = csv.DictReader(f)
        if colname:
            yield from (row[colname] for row in f_csv)
        else:
            yield from f_csv
```

### Parens

```
format(method.__name__,(end-start)))
```

can lose the inner-most parens.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your advices, it is very valuable for me!
 My self.data register all informations that i get after doing the "post" request (data retrieved from the request (like fiscal revenue etc...), as metadata about success/failure of the request with the reasons ) like this i can retrieve and analyze later the informations (from the object). So i do need to store rhis req.ok. I will put a link of my github project to clear some points!  However i will integrate the other corrections you pointed out :)